# Extracting substring from the middle of a string in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I'm trying to extract a substring from a class type returned as a string:

```
'::Pos::EmailNotice'
'Pos::EmailNotice'
'::Pos::CallNotice'
'Pos::CallNotice'
```

So if I get a string 'Pos::{type}Notice', I would need to end up with {type}.

I've tried to use `#slice` as well as `#delete_prefix` and `#delete_suffix` but I'd like it to be more dynamic than that just in case the namespacing gets changed or we add more types of notices in the future.

I tried searching here but I couldn't find any answers explaining how to extract text in a case like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails provides [`String#demodulize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-demodulize) to strip the namespace off a module:

```
'::Pos::EmailNotice'.demodulize #=> "EmailNotice"
'Pos::EmailNotice'.demodulize   #=> "EmailNotice"
'::Pos::CallNotice'.demodulize  #=> "CallNotice"
'Pos::CallNotice'.demodulize    #=> "CallNotice"
```

You could use that along with [`delete_suffix!`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/String.html#method-i-delete_suffix-21), e.g.

```
string = '::Pos::EmailNotice'

string.demodulize.delete_suffix!('Notice')
#=> "Email"
```

Another approach would be to convert the string to the actual class and have it implement a `type` method that you can call, e.g.:

```
module Pos
  class EmailNotice
    def self.type
      :email
    end
  end
end
```

You could then use Rails' [`String#constantize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize):

```
'::Pos::EmailNotice'.contantize.type #=> :email
'Pos::EmailNotice'.contantize.type   #=> :email
```

or with pure Ruby via [`Module#const_get`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Module.html#method-i-const_get):

```
Object.const_get('::Pos::EmailNotice').type #=> :email
Object.const_get('Pos::EmailNotice').type   #=> :email
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it always ends in `Notice` then this is probably the simplest:

```rb
main> %w[ ::Pos::EmailNotice Pos::EmailNotice ::Pos::CallNotice Pos::CallNotice ].map do |s|
main>   s.match(/([^:]+)Notice/)[1]
main> end
["Email", "Email", "Call", "Call"]
```

Which is basically saying "all non ':' chars before 'Notice'".

Comment: There's also `s[/([^:]+)Notice/, 1]` which simply returns `nil` when no match was found. And you might want to add a `\z` anchor to match the string's end.

Comment: Wow, TIL, thanks! I've always done a `if x = s.match ... x[1]` thing, but that's a really nice syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [ "::Pos::EmailNotice",
        "Pos::EmailNotice", 
        "::Pos::CallNotice",
        "Pos::CallNotice"
      ]
```

```
arr.map { |str| str[/[^:]*(?=Notice\z)/] }
  #=> ["Email", "Email", "Call", "Call"]
```

---

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BAhMLD/1)

The demo employs the PCRE regex engine. Though different in some ways to Ruby's Onigmo regex engine, in this case they give the same result. I've used the end-of-line anchor (`$`) rather than the end-of-string anchor (`\z`) in order to test the expression against multiple strings.

This employs the method [String#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) with a regular expression as its argument.

---

The regular expression reads, "Match zero or more (`*`) characters other than (`^`) a colon to be followed by the literal "Notice" at the end of the string (`\z`)".

`(?=Notice\z)` is a *positive lookahead*.

You may wish to hover the cursor over each part of the regular expression at the link to obtain an explanation of its function.

Answer (score 0):

Test strings

```
str = ['::Pos::EmailNotice', 'Pos::EmailNotice', 
  '::Pos::CallNotice', 'Pos::CallNotice', 'Pos::CallText']
```

Using `gsub`

```
str.map {|i| i.gsub /.*::|(Notice|Text)$/, ""}

["Email", "Email", "Call", "Call", "Call"]
```